# Как создать заготовки в VSCode, например как в Emmet

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

Извиняюсь, если глупый вопрос, но не нашёл в интернете, не знаю как правильно загуглить, чтобы найти его.
Дело в том, что я хотел бы сделать эдакие "заготовки", например:

Ввожу я в VSCode: `df` нажимаю табуляцию и она конвертируется в:

```
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
```

Такое присутствует в WebStorm, есть ли такое в VSCode?

Comment: emmet и в vscode тоже

Comment: Emmet это уже готовые заготовки для HTML.
А мне нужно для CSS создать свои заготовки, чтобы по моим буквам конвертировались в стили, которые укажу.

Comment: и для css тоже h100%+w50px в этом духе

Comment: Да-да, я понимаю. Но еще раз говорю, я хочу создать свои заготовки
Вот пример же привёл. А df конвертируется в обычный display: flex

Comment: открой настройки emmet и поменяй на свои ..ил вообще своё напиши ...закажи ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такая функция называется "сниппет".
Она присутствует в VSCode. Можно создавать свои сниппеты такие, как я и привёл в примере.